# Function with 2 variables by the chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> If $u=f(x-t)+g(x+t)$ then prove that
>
> $$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
>  $$

In my opinon we should use the chain rule.

Comment: Ok, why don't you try it and let us know what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
u_x(x,t) = f'(x-t) + g'(x+t)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$u_x(t)=f(x-t)+g(x+t)$$

$$u_x'(t)=-f'(x-t)+g'(x+t)$$

$$u_x''(t)=f''(x-t)+g''(x+t)$$

Here is indeed the chain rule used. Keep in mind that $x$ is a constant. And similiar we get the following:

$$u_t(x)=f(x-t)+g(x+t)$$

$$u_t'(x)=f'(x-t)+g'(x+t)$$

$$u_t''(x)=f''(x-t)+g''(x+t)$$

We see that it holds. We also used that the derivative of $f+g$ is $f'+g'$.